# Reset the snap halfway point (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap, snap

So I use 'snap'ped windows a lot on my 32inch 1440p monitor. It's not quite the same as dual monitor but it's useful enough to be productive when I need two things open together.

However, at some point I accidentally clicked in the middle of the windows and dragged the middle bar out of position.

Now whenever I snap to one side or the other, they snap to this new alignment instead of taking up the absolute half of the screen.

I've tried doing 'show windows side by side' but that just makes two small windows at the far left of the screen for some reason.

How do I reset the 'snap' grid to be in the exact middle again? And even better, lock it to prevent future accidents?

For now I've drug the snap bar back to as close to the middle as I can but it bothers my OCD that I don't know if it's to-the-pixel exactly the middle anymore. Argh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a new window without any orientation or in Full screen should reset the middle bar.
   [image: Example reset with full screen window]
2. Moving the smaller side to the bigger also rest the middle bar.
   [image: Example reset with switching sides]

Comment: Thanks. Guess I couldn't tell much difference between where I had positioned it and where it went in a new window and didn't realize it was resetting. I tried putting the bar wildly off center and then snapping a new window, like you said, and it went to the halfway point. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. Would you than mind to accept/upvote the answerer?

Comment: I get an error that says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."